# nupassana or upassana?

Tags: pali-language, eightfold-path, sati

A Wikipedia article about Sati uses the word "upassanā"

> According to Grzegorz Polak, the four upassanā have been misunderstood by the developing Buddhist tradition, ...
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_(Buddhism)

However, I could not find the word in Pali dictionary and a Google search did not explain the term.
The term 'nupassana' however is found on Google but neither in Pali dictionar .

There is upasana in Sanskrit.

What is this term upassana or nupassana and where is it used?

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you're looking for is [Anupassanā](https://dsalsrv04.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/pali_query.py?qs=Anupassana&searchhws=yes)

> [abstr. of anupassati, cf. Sk. anudarśana] looking at, viewing, contemplating, consideration, realisation

It's used in compound words like [Kāyānupassanā](https://suttacentral.net/dn22/en/sujato) (and Vedanānupassanā, Cittānupassanā, and Dhammānupassanā).

The fact that the second 'a' in "Kāyānupassanā" is long (i.e. with an accent on it, 'ā') is I think a hint that it's a compound of two 'a's, i.e.

```
Kāya + anupassanā = Kāyānupassanā
```

---

Wikipedia's [Vipassanā (Etymology)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipassan%C4%81#Etymology) says ...

> Vipassanā is a Pali word derived from the older prefix "vi-" meaning "special", and the verbal root "-passanā" meaning "seeing". It is often translated as "insight" or "clear-seeing". The "vi" in vipassanā has many possible meanings, it could mean to '[see] into', '[see] through' or to '[see] in a special way.

... so there's a "root" "-passanā" -- which doesn't have an independent entry in the PTS dictionary, it just says ...

> 1. Passanā (p. 447) Passanā Passanā see anu˚, vi˚.

... i.e. referencing anupassanā and vipassanā.

---

The Sanskrit is [Pashyana or Paśyana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/pashyana) -- meaning "see", apparently.

Also there's https://www.buddha-vacana.org/toolbox/pref.html#anu which gives six possible meaning for the prefix "anu".

> 1. **after, behind** (motion viewed from the front backward).
>    ex: dhāvati: to run > anu·dhāvati: to run after
>
>    bala: military force > anu·bala: rearguard
>
>    bhāsati: to speak > anu·bhāsati: to speak after, repeat
> 2. **for, towards an aim, on to, into, over to, forward** (motion viewed from the back forward).
>    ex: pavecchati: to give, bestow > anu·pavecchati: to hand over
>
>    rodati: to cry, weep > anu·rodati: to cry for
>
>    pavisati: to enter > anu·pavisati: to enter into
> 3. **(emphasis)**.
>    ex: dayā: sympathy, kindness > anu·ddayā: pity
>
>    yoga: application, endeavour > anu·yoga: devotion, dedication
>
>    vitakketi: to consider, reflect > anu·vitakketi: to ponder over
> 4. **according to, in conformity with, along**.
>    ex: ñāta: kown, well-knwon > anu·ñāta: permitted, allowed
>
>    mati: opinion > anu·mati: consent, agreement
>
>    rūpa: form > anu·rūpa: conform
>
>    anu·dhamma: in conformity with the dhamma
>
>    karoti: to do > anu·karoti: to imitate
> 5. **secondary, supplementary, inferior, minor, smaller**.
>    ex: pabbajā: ascetic life > anu·pabbajā: discipleship in ascetism
>
>    majjha: average > anu·majjha: mediocre
>
>    pavatteti: to set in motion > anu·pavatteti: to keep in motion
> 6. **each, every, one by one**.
>    ex: disā: direction > anu·disā: each direction
>
>    pubba: previous, former > anu·pubba: 'each after the previous one' ie. gradual
>
>    pañcāha: five days > anu·pañcāha: every five days.

Answer (score 1):

[anupassanā](https://suttacentral.net/define/anupassan%C4%81?lang=en)
looking at, viewing, contemplating, consideration, realisation

[anu](https://suttacentral.net/define/anu?lang=en) small, minute, atomic; subtle. As prefix meaning “along”; with verbs of motion: “along towards”

passanā from verb [passati](https://suttacentral.net/define/passati?lang=en) to see; to recognise, to realise, to know, to find

anupassanā = "watching/observing/seeing closely"

Comment: Hi. I could mean "worship" but the phrase "four categories of mindfulness (sati)" sounds a bit unusual.